# Marquardt algorithm in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a Marquardt algorithm on R. I looked at the example on nls.lm function and tried to write something based on it. Here is my code.(result1 being a column of 262 values I need to do a best fit exponential smoothing over)

```
n=seq(1:262)

x=result1

#observed values
obs<-function(nn) x[nn+1] 

#exponentially smoothed values
pred<-function(p, nn) ifelse(nn==1, obs(0), p*obs(nn-1)+(1-p)*Recall(p, nn-1))

#residuals
resFun<-function(p, nn) obs(n)-pred(p, nn)

nls.out<-nls.lm(par=0.33, resFun, nn=n, control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1)))
```

But it keeps giving me this error.

```
Error in x[n + 1] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I realise it must be a ridiculously stupid mistake in the definitions of the  functions somewhere, but please have a look if you can see what am I doing wrong.
When I solved this in excel I started with p=0.33 and the solver got top=0.55114, this is basically what I am trying to get it to do, for it to find the best value 0.55114 starting from 0.33.

Thanks very much in advance and sorry for taking up your time.
Arpine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `pred` function:
it is not really vectorized and 
cannot even be called with the starting values.
You can rewrite it using a loop instead of recursion.

```
smooth <- function(x,alpha) {
  res <- x
  for(i in seq_along(x)[-1]) {
    res[i] <- (1-alpha) * res[i] + alpha * res[i-1]
  }
  res
}

library(minpack.lm)
x <- rnorm(20)
resFun <- function(alpha) {
  x - smooth(x, alpha)
}
r <- nls.lm(par=0.33, resFun, control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1))
```

The optimal value is, unsurprisingly, zero: 
the more you smooth the data, the farther away from the data you are.

Comment: It works!! Thanks so much! the only thing is that i didn't include x<-rnorm(20) , it messes up my x values, so i don't think you need it. also i have to play a bit with the indexes, but its a small thing and it works perfectly and gets close to what i wanted: ~0.55.

Thanks again!